# On page reload, all objects are destroyed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I make a persistent list of objects X that survives page reload / post-back in c# / asp.net ?
This was never a problem in c#, but in asp.net, a post-back will wipe out everything.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)?

Comment: you create them dynamically?

Comment: How were you ever coding in C# but not in .NET?  Or do you mean webforms specifically?

Comment: @Jeff I believe he put ASP.NET and not just .NET, unless he edited the post after you commented.

Comment: @mellamokb nope.. never heard of it

Comment: @Alex I need to add data to a gridview everytime a user clicks a button. But as the page reloads, the list wich the grid is connected to is set to null

Comment: @Half_Baked HTTP is Stateless.  What this means is when you're transferring data via HTTP, the transfer of data is treated as an independent transaction.  So, when you do a PostBack, any data you might have had available won't be available unless you implement a different solution.

Comment: @MikeMarks Yes, I know, just didnt know what it was actually called a "stateless protocol" Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always save your items to the current Session.

For example:

```
Session["var1"] = // whatever you want
```

And your Session object will exist until the current session expires regardless of PostBacks.

Comment: But how do I add objects to a list, everytime the page reloads/post-back?

Comment: Well, with Session all you can do is use the Session object.  So for example, you can iterate through a list of items using a foreach loop, and assign Session["Item" + counter] to its value.

Comment: So what I would probably do is on the event that causes the post back, go ahead and store those values into the Session.

Comment: I must try this :) It's a button-click btw, wich adds an objects to a list (and also fires post-back)

Comment: In a perfect world though I wouldn't think that you would have to do it this way.  I don't know the specifics of your situation beyond what you've already said, but when you're dealing with stateless you've got to think out of the box ya know! @HalfBaked

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net is built for [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol which is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), so you can not find the object on post back.  You can use view state instead.

### ViewState

> Microsoft® ASP.NET view state, in a nutshell, is the technique used by
>   an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form
>   across postbacks.

### The Role of View State

> View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there to persist state
>   across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state is the property
>   values of the controls that make up its control hierarchy.) This begs
>   the question, "What sort of state needs to be persisted?" To answer
>   that question, let's start by looking at what state doesn't need to be
>   persisted across postbacks. Recall that in the instantiation stage of
>   the page life cycle, the control hierarchy is created and those
>   properties that are specified in the declarative syntax are assigned.
>   Since these declarative properties are automatically reassigned on
>   each postback when the control hierarchy is constructed, there's no
>   need to store these property values in the view state.

Comment: Hm, I hear you. Will enabling sessing state or viewstate help me? Or Should I solve this some other way?

Comment: You can use viewstate but if you have small data as it increased the request / response size.

Comment: Best thing maybe is to somehow disable the postback? I think it can be done with jquery, but not c#